# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066

Tags: php, mysql, phalcon

I am working in PHP Phalcon with Xampp server.

I have an heirarchy of models:

> UsersAbstract is parent to UserOfficials, UserPatients.
>
> UsersOfficial is parent to OfficialDoctor.

The tables in the database have the same names as the models above, except the names are in camel case, like User_Officials and so on. Just the table for UsersAbstract is not named in camel case. The reason is that in the early days of developement of this project, I came across an error which was resolved by changing the name to UsersAbstract instead of Users_Abstract.

Anyway, so now I am trying to run a code and the error causing snippet is here:

```
foreach ($available_users as $user)
{
  $select_doctor = "Select "
         ."UserOfficials.Occupation,"
         ."UsersAbstract.Full_Name,"
         ."UserOfficials.Doc_ID "
         ."from UserOfficials join UsersAbstract "
         ."On UserOfficials.Unique_ID = UsersAbstract.Unique_ID"
         ." Where UserOfficials.Unique_ID = :uid:";

  $doctor_details = $this->modelsManager->executeQuery($select_doctor, array("uid" => $user->Unique_ID));

   if ($doctor_details->occupation == "Doctor")
        $this->available_doctor = $doctor_details;
}
```

I am trying to separate a doctor from the list of available users. The error that I am receiving is this

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'usersabstract'
```

Both UserOfficials and UsersAbstract tables have a column named Unique_ID to link them to each other.

EDIT: I added the Join Condition

[solved]

The UsersAbstract class had a function "getSource()". The Function was not overloaded in the children and grandchildren classes. This is why the error was observed in my code. When I uniquely set sources of each model class, the issue was resolved.

Comment: there is no join condition.[join syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: By the way, `thisIsCamelCase` and `this_is_snake_case` and I `don'tKnow_whyYou_would_mixThem_in_theSame_databaseSchema`

Comment: Okay, I was confused then

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

```
$select_doctor = "Select "
     ."UserOfficials.Occupation,"
     ."UsersAbstract.Full_Name,"
     ."UserOfficials.Doc_ID "
     ."from UserOfficials join UsersAbstract "
     ."ON (UserOfficials.Unique_ID = UsersAbstract.Unique_ID)"
     ."WHERE UserOfficials.Unique_ID = :uid: AND UsersAbstract.Unique_ID = :uid:";
```

Comment: Your table name is `UsersAbstract`,then why its showing `Not unique table/alias: 'usersabstract'`

Comment: DB is case insensitive. When I made table in XAMPP I named them all like this but automatically they convert to the lower case.

Comment: But that is not important, other statements in other controllers are working

Comment: I changed the spellings, it seems to divert from the current problem